# How to perform load balancing for a python API

Tags: python, rest, mapreduce, load-balancing

I have build as application with REST API.

I have to send request from a cluster (of about 10 nodes) to get some information from this API.

Now if I run it on single system, it is expected that it may become a bottleneck and mapreduce job will take a lot of time to complete.

Is there any way or solution that I can run this service on multiple systems for load balancing?. I am using Linux OS. My service is built in Python and I am using Flash to get it via REST.

Comment: Run more API instances. Put a load balancer / proxy on them... That's how regular websites scale.

Comment: Generally the web servers all have the load balancer / proxy  functions. If you know how to config the web server configuration file.

Comment: What proxy server are you using? It is hosted in any of the cloud instances?

Comment: I hope Apache HTTPD or HA-Proxy would work for this purpose with simple LB configuration.